# edmware Update Failed with 22.04 in Dell Latitude 7280

Tags: updates, 22.04, firmware

Once the system update is downloaded the update is not getting any impact with failing result.

[image: Once the system update downloaded the update is not getting any impact with failing result...]

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 in my Dell Latitude 7280 there is a notification about a system update, and once I click on the update it prompts me to restart, but when I click the restart it doesn't restart. I've gone through the same question on askubuntu.com. There they suggest a cold boot after downloading the update, but once I tried the cold boot after switching on the laptop it shows me Firmware Update Failed. What am I missing here?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written is unclear. You mention that you asked the same question on askubuntu.com, but that is this site. Has this question been cross-posted? Finally, where are you getting the "firmware update failed" message: as a boot message, or from Ubuntu? You may want to edit your question to better clarify the issue. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to boot your system or have you access to uefi menu?

Comment: Please disable secure boot in your uefi settings